# Pylint: overriding max-line-length in individual file

Tags: python, pylint

Is it possible to change `max-line-length` settings for one file out of a project (while performing all other checks defined in rc file on it)?

Ideally, it should behave like inline `pylint: disable=x` comments.

I've tried putting this line at the module level:

```py
# pylint: max-line-length=240
```

PyLint failed to recognize it:

```py
my_file.py:15: [E0011(unrecognized-inline-option), ] Unrecognized file option 'max-line-length
```

Edit: I know I can disable `line-too-long` check entirely, but to be honest I'd like to avoid doing so, just in case anyone would try to extend this module and add lines even longer than they are now.

Comment: From what I understand, you can only enable/disable checks in the inline comment, e.g. `# pylint: disable=C0301`, where C0301 is a [code](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes) for a "Line too long" check.

Answer (score 82):

You can create `.pylintrc` file in your python script to overwrite pylint settings and put inside

```
[FORMAT]
max-line-length=240
```

edit 240 based on your choice.

Comment: This setting goes under the heading `[FORMAT]`.

Comment: sample .pylintrc configuration file - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datawire/quark/master/.pylintrc

Comment: There is also a pylint command to create the default file. eg: `pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc`

Answer (score 23):

According to [the doc](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#messages-control-options), I think you cannot modify the pylint config in line.
but you can disable the warning for only one or few line(s) with `# pylint: disable=line-too-long`:

```
# disable for only one line
ridiculously_long_variable_name = "this is not a ridiculously long and useless python line"  # pylint: disable=line-too-long

# disable for few (or more) lines 
# pylint: disable=line-too-long
ridiculously_long_variable_name = "this is not a ridiculously long and useless python line"
# pylint: enable=line-too-long
```

Comment: This seems to work better than the `# pylint: disable=C0301` mentioned elsewhere, at least when working with different analysis tools like Sonarqube for code quality analysis. Wise managers track how many ignore/disable lines you have as a code smell, hit snooze too often and eventually you wake up without a job because the software you wrote is a steaming pile of poo.

Answer (score 19):

```
pylint --max-line-length=240
```

works for me.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the additional as below:
`C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint.exe --max-line-length=240 <PATH TO FILE>`